# React Native access app notification permission

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, permissions

I want to reach the permissions shown in the picture. How can I do with React Native?

Best Regards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDf5z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use native Java code using Native Modules in React native, if you have Native Java knowledge then

```
 public void appDetailsSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + reactContext.getPackageName()));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(reactContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        reactContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

Otherwise you can use a third party library, such as https://github.com/levelasquez/react-native-android-open-settings

Comment: thanks for the answer.
How can I get permission without sending the user to the setting screen?

Comment: You can use PermissionsAndroid for Android its a react native util using this you can request permission from the user and check the status of a permission.

For iOS you have to use custom solutions which requires some knowledge of Creating Naitve Modules.